# Memory management of Quartz Scheduler in case of thread unavailability

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

Hope you are doing well.

I'm trying to understand the memory management of Quartz Scheduler. For that I’m having two questions:

1. For example, I'm having 10 worker threads for Quartz and all are occupied with executing the job. At the same time, we got triggers for another 10 jobs to execute. Now this is for sure quartz will for the availability of the threads. But will those new 10 jobs be loaded in the JVM or will remain in the Database (we have used JDBC as the job store type) until getting thread allocation?
2. If I’m running two instances of my application and shared DB for job store persistence, then to avoid race conditions between the two instances what should I have to do so that one Job executes only once? Is it maintained by the quartz itself?

I tried to look into the documentation but did not get any clue about it.

Thanks in advance.

Regards